# Using SPServices to return a List value for comparison

Tags: list, javascript, spservices, html

I have this code that uses SPServices to get the value from a List column...in this case the Body column from the Announcements List. The code works and it will append the Body to the HTML list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Body' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") + "</li>";    
        alert($(this).attr("ows_Body")); 
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml); 
      });
    }
  });
});
```

However, I have a couple of challenges that I can't seem to figure out.

I'm trying to get the value from the Body column in the SharePoint List, for this purpose, we can say it has a value of "Hello World" however:

```
$(this).attr("ows_Body")
```

returns

```
"<div class="ExternalClassD831897642D94F6B816CFF029C96787F"><p>Hello World<br></p></div>"
```

instead of just returning "Hello World"

**How can I change the code to get this output without the 'div' and 'p' tags ?**

**The reason for this is because I want to be able to compare this value to another and execute some code whether it is true of false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have created the body field as rich enhanced type.You can create div and append the field value then get the innerText as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Body' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") + "</li>";  
    var div= document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = $(this).attr("ows_Body");  
    alert(div.innerText); 
    $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml); 
    });
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why the ``async:false``??

Comment: In simple words when set async false that means you will block execute the script until the SPServices finished.
  see this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/131352/66149 ,I think explained why and when use the async deeply.